# Prevent PhoneGap image gallery from out of memory

Tags: cordova, android-camera, out-of-memory, phonegap-plugins

my app (Android) needs to choose a photo from image gallery. After choosing it needs to show up on the screen. If i choose a small image (e.g. 1024x768) it works well. If I choose a bigger image (e.g. some which is shot with the camera before) the app restars and returns to my index.html without an exception on logcat.

This is my code:

```
function getPhoto(source) {
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 100,
            destinationType : navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType:source});
    }
```

I´m sure it´s an out of memory error. But with the upper code there is no need to load the image into the memory. Theres no need for phonegap to resize it (with targetHeight...) or to correct the orientation.

I´m running out of solutions...

If you need: this is onPhotoURISuccess(imageURL)

```
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {

        // Button Variablen zuweisen
        var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');
        var button_capture = document.getElementById('button_capture');
        var button_album = document.getElementById('button_album');

        // Nicht gebrauchte Buttons verstecken
        button_capture.style.display = 'none';
        button_album.style.display = 'none';


        // Ausgewähltes Foto anzeigen
        smallImage.src = imageURI;
        smallImage.style.display = 'block';

        // Upload Button einblenden
        var upload_button = document.getElementById('upload_button_album');
        upload_button.style.display = 'block';

        // Wert für Übergabe an Funktion in globale Variable speichern
        myImage = imageURI; 
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Trying it with this options, causes the app to restart too:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 40,
            destinationType : navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType:source, 
            targetWidth:1024, 
            targetHeight:768});
```